# When designing an Access 2007 report, the keyboard nudge factor is changing to strange increments..?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

When designing reports in Access 2007, I use the keyboard extensively to move & resize the controls; keys such as `Tab`, `Arrows`, `Shift`, `Ctrl`, `Shift+Ctrl`, etc.

I seem to recall the `Shift+Arrow` keys would resize controls *precisely* to the `Form.GridX` and `Form.GridY` values. So if the grid value was 10, `Shift+Arrow` would change the size 1.0", 1.1", 1.2", 1.3", etc. BUT...now it does not. The values have become...bizarre.

Now I find the controls changing to **odd** increments, and the values are changing **before my eyes**. It's raising havoc, because all my controls are off by hairs and I have to use the property boxes to type the exact values.

For instance, imagine if you will...a textbox with the precise values:

- `Top:    1.0"`
- `Left:   1.0"`
- `Width:  1.0"`
- `Height: 0.2"`

When I use `Shift+Left` and `Shift+Right` to "wiggle" the width back & forth at (approximately) the 1" point, it hits me back with values such as 0.9965, 0.9972,  0.9986, 0.9993...a regular barrage of inaccurate values. And then...finally...sometimes...it will actually land precisely on 1.000. It's like there's some kind of pixel dithering happening. But this randomness..? I don't recall ever seeing anything like it before.

How can I fix this..? Is it even fixable..?

What have I done to troubleshoot so far..? See below.

- A new blank ACCDB file.
- Checked through the Access settings for a `Nudge` value.
- Rebooted.
- Searched Google and StackOverflow.
- Changed display resolution.
- Changed the Windows 7 'Custom Text DPI'.
- Tried 'Windows XP style DPI scaling', on & off.
- Different textbox fonts, sizes, and weights.

I've run out of ideas.

I haven't tried other versions or other computers because I don't have any available at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Format tab in your form's property sheet.  If the Grid X and Grid Y values are not set to 24, your nudge will be off.

Comment: It cannot be a specific value other than 24, with the nudge factor compensating accordingly..? It seems if GridX and GridY are both set to 10, it would make things easier, with less decimals, since we use a base-10 numbering system. =-/

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I believe it has something to do with the conversion of font points to inches. 72 points (1 inch) / 24 = 3.  So setting it at 24 causes the box to nudge 3 font points.  Setting it at 10 would make it nudge 7.2 font points, which I think Access would have to round causing your inches to be off.

Comment: That's about right. The relevant thing is that Access sizes things to [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip), which are 1/1440 of an inch. Take into account that, and you can come up with some more valid grid values.

Comment: But why does the nudge *change*..? If I click on a control and use Shift+Left and Shift+Right back & forth over the same spot without letting go of the shift key, the value that it lands on is different every time. That's the part that seems very, very strange. It seems to me it should decide on the same value every time it passes over the same spot on the form.

Comment: Also, at some point this worked correctly, or more precisely - as I expect it should, because I clearly remember working on a form and having the increments be increments of 1/8th inch, such as 1.125, 1.625, etc. And it was hitting them exactly every time.